# Removing a line causes the browser to freeze

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

With this line removed from the code, the browser freezes, how come?

How would I prevent that from ever happening?

Is the code written wrong where that is even able to happen in the first place?

`apiIsReady = true;` **Removed**

Try clicking on a play button on the image and the browser freezes.

https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/49/

`apiIsReady = true;` **Added**

https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/30/

Comment: why you want to remove this?

Comment: I want to know how come the browser freezes when that line is removed from the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `apiIsReady` set to true, you are creating loop that adds new value to array with each iteration of that same array.

```
function load_all_waitting_inits()
{
  for(var opts of waitting_inits) // new values are being added with each iteration, preventing loop to end
  {
    init(opts); // parse value of waitting_inits array
  }
}

function init(opts) {
    loadPlayer();
    if (apiIsReady) { // always false
      addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
    }
    else
    {
      waitting_inits.push(opts) // here you are adding values infinitely
    }
}
```

## Edit

Check if array includes object.

```
function init(opts) {
    loadPlayer();
    if (apiIsReady) {
      addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
    }
    else if(!waitting_inits.includes(opts)) // if array doesn't include opts then push
    {
      waitting_inits.push(opts)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I be adding this to the code replacing the other one?

Comment: You could check if array contains that value, if not, then push it.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you provide a jsfiddle of it so I can see?

Comment: Now it takes 2 Clicks for a video to load, instead of 1 Click. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/51/   / Compared to  1 Click and the video loads. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/30/ How would that be fixed in your code?

Comment: Do you see what I mean? In your edit: It takes 2 Clicks for a video to load. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/51/ / Here it takes only 1 Click for a video to load. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/30/ How would your code be fixed so a video loads in 1 Click, and 'not' 2 Clicks? What would need to be adjusted to resolve, fix that issue?

Comment: It's just a typo in `waitting_inits` name, made edit.

Comment: Can you explain for me what's the difference between Your Way: https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/54/ / And how this does it? https://jsfiddle.net/h93qzu0t/1/ What's the difference and better approach?

Comment: No I can't. I'm not a teacher, you have mistaken the purpose of this site. Learn JavaScript if you can't see the difference.

Comment: That won't make much of a difference, you are iterating through empty array so it's not executing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `apiIsReady = true;` then it creates an infinity loop. And that's why, the browser will freeze.